# How to mock method in extended trait with Mockito

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest, traits

How can I mock dependend traits with mockito?
I have two traits:

```
 trait A {
    def a = 1
  }

  trait B extends A {
    def b = {
      // do things
      a
      // do things
    }
  }
```

Now, I want to test Trait B. And I want to verify, that A.a() gets called:

```
class SmallTest extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar {
  test("prove, that a gets called") {
    val mockA = mock[A]
    val b = new B with mockA {}  // This won't compile
    b.b
    verify(mockA).a
  }
}
```

This example won't compile. But how would I "inject" my mock otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a way. This will work. Maybe a bit unhandy, if there are a lot methods, I have to override...
In this example I added method parameters to the method I want to mock, to show the repetition, which doesn't look very nice.

```
  trait A {
    def a(i: Int) = i + 1
  }

  trait B extends A {
    def b(j: Int) = {
      // do things
      a(j)
      // do things
    }
  }

  test("prove, that a gets called") {
    val mockA = mock[A]
    val b = new B {
      override def a(j: Int) = mockA.a(j)
    }
    b.b(1)
    verify(mockA).a(1)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spy would be a better choice. [mockito spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T))

```
// the class being spied cannot be final,
// so we cannot do this:
// spy(new B {})

class C extends B

val c = spy(new C)
c.b
verify(c).a
```

Comment: I'm having the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711951/unit-testing-class-that-extends-a-trait-how-do-i-mock-and-stub-methods-in-the).  The problem with Spys is that they still call the real code which I don't want to do in this case, because the method I want to verify has an interaction with a database.